# Modules disable after upgrade 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, module

Good afternoon,
I recently upgraded from version 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 through **composer**
It happens that some modules were disabled during the upgrade, I would like to know the reason and what I do with them (remove?)

List of disabled modules:

> Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
>   Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
>   Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
>   Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
>   Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you disabled inventory management

[Source](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/)

It's for Multi Source Inventory (MSI) project 
Check do you have this in your composer.json

```
magento/inventory-composer-metapackage = ^1.1.0
```

And from this link above

> 2.2.X Magento installation to Magento 2.3.X, Inventory Management modules will be disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The modules you listed belong to MSI 1.1.1 which is deployed along with Magento 2.3.1. 
All these modules supposed to be enabled if MSI was enabled before. If it was disabled beforehand on Magento 2.3.0 - the new modules should be disabled as well. You can read more about this here - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/MSI-Release-Notes-and-Installation#msi-110

Created corresponding ticket for your case - here https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2217
don't hesitate to provide more details